# How to intercept sent / consumed RabbitMQ messages

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, amqp

I am developing `RabbitMQ` token auth plugin, where the token needs to be included in AMQP header so it can be validated upon every sent / consumed message.

I am wondering how can I achieve it? So far I am only familiar with `RabbitMQ` auth plugins and do not know much about other plugin mechanisms. After quick research I have found `rabbit_channel_interceptor` behavior which sounds like it could do the job.

Answer (score -1):

I have read rabbitmq's source code about auth. In the source code tree, please pay attention to the files named as `"rabbit_auth_machanism.erl", "rabbit_auth_backend", "rabbit_auth_backend_internal"`. In addition, there is another plugin named `"xxx ldap"`. 
After reading carefully and know how to integrate and build the rabbitmq project groups, you can start programming.